# Typedef Code duplication. Template types within template types

Tags: c++, templates, duplication

I am new to C++... So, this question might be silly...

I do have, for example, the following struct

```
template<typename _TpIn, typename _TpOut>
struct TypesKernel {
    typedef _TpIn input_type;
    typedef _TpOut output_type;
};
```

And now I want to use it within templates. For example:

```
template<typename _TypesKernel>
class A {
    typedef typename _TypesKernel::input_type input_type;
    typedef typename _TypesKernel::output_type output_type;
    ....
};
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid this typedef duplications for any class I want to use TypesKernel with?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: A remark about naming: names which begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (among others) are reserved to the implementation. (You could rename `_TpIn` to `TpIn_` for example.) As concerns the question: I often see code like that (but see answers below).

Comment: Well, I took it from std, but may be it is not a good example... =)))

Comment: Ah I see :) well names in `std` are considered "implementation" so they have the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the typedefs there, the only way I see them included is to either define as you do or inherit from something. Your class might use TypesKernel  as base class, or they both could use a common base class that has nothing but the typedefs.  (like in `std::` framework for iterators).

However inheriting is not necessarily better, you might live with the duplication in many cases.